# WinEvent Telling the different objects apart?

Tags: c++, windows, hook, get-winevent

I’m listening to global win events for cases such as object destroyed, hidden, shown, created etc…

However I’d like to do certain things based on what that handle (HWND) is. For example did a button just get hidden or destroyed or did a window? Was it a child window that got hidden or parent? The last question regards to seemingly getting an event raised for every object in the parent window when parent window closes which is too much noise. Trying to make sense of what raised the event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents

Answer (score 0):

Windows offers a rich set of functions for interrogating an `HWND`.  For example (error checking omitted for brevity):

> did a button just get hidden or destroyed or did a window?

```
TCHAR classname [32];
GetClassName (hWnd, classname, 32);
if (_tcscmp (classname, __T ("BUTTON")) == 0)
    ...
```

> Was it a child window that got hidden or parent?

```
LONG dwStyle = GetWindowLong (hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
if (dwStyle & WS_CHILD)
    ...
```

> an event [is] raised for every object in the parent window when parent window closes which is too much noise.

I think you are stuck with this.  When a parent window is destroyed, it automatically destroys all its children, and each of those will send the corresponding event(s) as a result.

Comment: Well if i can get the class name I can just conditionally make sure it’s a window and ignore buttons right? What might be tricky is knowing when a child window actually closed vs it’s parent closing and hence closing the child.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment, but if you want to test whether an `HWND` is a button, you need to explicitly test the class name against "BUTTON" as shown in my example code.

Comment: I made an edit didn’t anticipate you responding so fast. I think I get that part not home to test but now I’m wondering how to know if a child window closed on its own vs it’s parent closing it because parent closed. Maybe there is a flag I can check that’s says closing or something?

Comment: No worries.  I can see that the second part of your comment might be tricky, but the close (or, perhaps, destroy) notifications for the children probably come in before the parent, if that helps at all.

Comment: My testing does seem to indicate that’s the case but I suppose another issue is at play since my handle checks seem to confuse the parent for the child and I’m assuming each handle is supposed to be unique/different thanks for the help so far I’ll test more when I get home